# How to access number in Enum Property?

Tags: scripting, rigging

I want to set sub surf value by reading number from the Enum Property

How do i do that ?

```
import bpy
def SubSurfSet(self, context):
    print(self.value)
    #bpy.context.object.modifiers["Subsurf"].render_levels = 2

bpy.types.PoseBone.SubSurfEnum = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
            #(identifier, name, description, icon, number)
    items = [('None','No Smooth','','',0), 
             ('Smooth','Smooth','','',1),
             ('Smoother','Smoother','','',2),
             ('Smoothest','Smoothest','','',4)],
    name = "Mask the MESH",
    default = 'None',
    update = SubSurfSet)

bpy.data.objects["Frog rig"].pose.bones["root.dummy"].SubSurfEnum = 'None'
```

Comment: Note that you do not need the second `''` for each item, as the last value will be registered as the number if no icon is provided. https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.EnumProperty

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What I would do is design the items of Enum property like this:

```
items = [('0','No Smooth',''), 
         ('1','Smooth',''),
         ('2','Smoother',''),
         ('4','Smoothest','')]
```

Then you just need to cast it to int.

```
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Subsurf"].render_levels = int(self.SubSurfEnum )
```

When you change this Enum property and the subsurf levels you don't have to change any dictionary.

Comment: I am already using this method, but need to know the use of assigning number in #(identifier, name, description, icon, number)

Comment: @ashwin The three first elements of the items are mandatory (identifier, name, description). The identifier is used for python access and other values are used for the interface only. The forth optional one is either the (unique!) number id of the item or, if followed by a fifth element (which must be the number id), an icon string identifier.

Comment: Self.value dose not exist. Self.SubSuefEnum gets the identifier. So dippending on identifier i have to check and assign values! In this case int helped

Comment: @zeffi you are righ

Answer (score 10):

Just for the record, it's also possible to access the enum items via `bpy.types` to look up all their properties:

```
items = bpy.types.PoseBone.bl_rna.properties['SubSurfEnum'].enum_items

pbone = bpy.context.selected_pose_bones[0] # some PoseBone
number = items[pbone.SubSurfEnum].value
# or access another property:    .icon
#                                .identifier
#                                .description
```

It's much more complicated if multiple items use the same identifier / name with different values however, because you can't lookup the right entry (I believe it will always pick the first with that name).

Comment: does this also work for enum props that have a dynamic item list via a callback function? I tried it and it didn't seem to work.

Is there a way to get identifiere,value,icon for enum properties with a dynamic item list?

Comment: It might not be possible to access dynamic enums this way, but I guess you could call that callback function yourself to retrieve all entries.

Answer (score 3):

```
import bpy

bpy.types.Object.SubSurfEnum = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
            #(identifier, name, description, icon, number)
    items = [('None','No Smooth','','',0), 
             ('Smooth','Smooth','','',1),
             ('Smoother','Smoother','','',2),
             ('Smoothest','Smoothest','','',4)],
    name = "Mask the MESH",
    default = 'None')

bpy.data.objects[0].SubSurfEnum = 'Smooth' # You have to assign something to this value first
print(bpy.data.objects[0].SubSurfEnum) # this print 'Smooth'
print(bpy.data.objects[0]['SubSurfEnum']) # this print 1 <---- ANSWER
```

Note that You have to assign something to this value first, or else You get

```
KeyError: 'bpy_struct[key]: key "SubSurfEnum1" not found'
```

Comment: In combination with CoDEmanX's answer `default =  ob.bl_rna.properties['SubSurfEnum'].default` is  "None"  `default_value = ob.bl_rna.properties['SubSurfEnum'].enum_items[default].value` is zero, and from your answer `ob.get("SubSurfEnum", default_value)` will give you the int value without having to set it first.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to use a dict.. to map from the string value to an int

```
def SubSurfSet(self, context):
    remap = dict(NoSmooth=0, Smooth=1, Smoother=2, Smoothest=4)
    val = remap.get(self.SubSurfEnum)
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Subsurf"].render_levels = val
```

Though, admittedly, this looks a little repetitive. Warning: I use 'NoSmooth' instead of 'None', to avoid confusion.